imposter-syndrome tag?
Should we consider adding an imposter-syndrome tag? A recent post on Academia SE had me looking at this, and emotional-responses and psychology which are commonly used tags don't quite seem to capture it. Given its prevalence in academia, just thought I would raise the question here.
A search of "imposter syndrome" as a keyword returns 200 results, but is there a threshold number for consider this?

The [tag:psychology] tag should be used for questions about the field of psychology, but what makes you say that [tag:emotional-responses] doesn't capture impostor syndrome? The tag description is "On emotional issues such as guilt, discouragement, jealousy, anxiety or feelings of inadequacy affecting academics and researchers."

Perhaps less that it is not subsumed within the broad category of emotional responses, but that imposter-syndrome is specifically focused and prevalent enough that it might warrant a breakout tag of its own. This would allow a seemingly common topic to be differentiated from the other more general emotional-responses. Similar to 'coursework' vs 'phd' and 'masters' and other broad/narrow categories. I'm new, so if there are more stringent guidelines for deciding this, beyond the "what are tags and how should I use them" page. I'd be happy to have a look.

I haven’t checked this, but I would guess that despite the several search results there are few questions where the asker would tag them like this from the start. After all one of the key features of the impostor syndrome is that you are not aware of it.

In general the criteria for a new tag are not number of mentions, but whether it would help anybody to categorise questions, e.g., to find answers to one’s question before posting it or for experts to find questions that you can answer.

Perhaps imposter-syndrome should be a synonym of emotional-responses?

@cag51, it isn't an emotional response, but it might be a "health" issue. Response to what, exactly?

This seems like a reasonable question, but I'm unenthusiastic for the reason that I don't think a new tag will greatly enhance the findability of questions on this topic. Meanwhile it does have the very real possibility of making question askers feel even worse if community users add such a tag to a question as a frame challenge.

Yes, I suppose if the term is mentioned in the discussion and responses, it would be couched to minimize any insult in the explanation of the term, rather than just a cold slapping of that tag on their question. If one didn't know the term, it might be badly received.

I don't see the need for this. Usually imposter syndrome is suggested by those answering questions, not those asking them. It is something the asker doesn't normally recognize in themself.
I wonder how many of those 200 search results are in questions, rather than answers. A quick scan suggests about a quarter of them are from the OP. And in some (many?) of them the OP rejects imposter syndrome as a reason for their question/problem.
Such a tag might be added by a reader in such cases, but that would, I think, fundamentally change the nature of the question itself.
OTOH, I have a very high standard for new tags and often delete new ones that seem misplaced. Some users confuse tags with keywords and we already have search for keywords.
